SQL Date columns comparison resulting in NULL date being shown as higher than actual date?
I have a very simple test I am trying to do where I compare two date columns to determine which occurs later than the other.
The statement is a simple:
case when Date1 > Date2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end

For the most part this works exactly as expected but when Date2 has a NULL value in it, that NULL value is considered as a 'No' in above query. In essence, the statement is resolving to say that Date1, which has some kind of date on it, is less than Date2 when Date2 is NULL.
Is this meant to be happening or am I missing a trick?

"that NULL value is considered as a 'No' in above query." No it's considered unknown, and 'yes' is only returned if Date1 > Date2 is true; unknown (and false) isn't true.

That is how NULL works. It is essentially asking is Date1 > [unkown]. It can't be true so it falls to the else.

If you need to account for NULL do a ISNULL(Date#, SomeDate)  Where somedate is either 1-1-1900 as default or higher like 1/1/2099  depending on what results you want the null value to turn into Yes or No

SQL uses three valued logic. If you need to distinguish the three cases you need three branches. case when Date1 > Date2 then 'True' when NOT Date1 > Date2 then 'False' ELSE 'Unknown' end
